# RestKit - RKFetchedResultsTableController : mapObjectsWithClass

Tags: objective-c, ios5, restkit

Hi,

I'm using a `RKFetchedResultsTableController` in order to fetch data from my WS and drive my tableview.

I'm using `RKTableViewCellMapping` to map my model & cells.

Here's how I set up the cellMapping :

```c
RKTableViewCellMapping *cellMapping = [RKTableViewCellMapping cellMapping];
cellMapping.cellClassName = @"CrudCategoryCell";
cellMapping.reuseIdentifier = @"CrudCategory";
cellMapping.rowHeight = 100; 
[cellMapping mapKeyPath:@"name.name" toAttribute:@"nameLabel.text"];
[cellMapping mapKeyPath:@"desc.desc" toAttribute:@"descLabel.text"];

[self.tableController mapObjectsWithClass:[CrudCategory class]            
                      toTableCellsWithMapping:cellMapping];
```

As you can see, my model is represented by one class : `CrudCategory`.

This class has two attributes : `name`, `desc`; respectively of type `CrudCategoryName` and `CrudCategoryDesc`.

These classes inherit from `NSManagedObject`.

When running the application :

```c
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Cannot build a tableView cell for object <NSManagedObject: 0x6c4fb90> 
(entity: CrudCategory; id: 0x6c4d900 <x-coredata://FA7323F8-519D-4AA9-AC6E-  BD30446B4C9B/CrudCategory/p210> ; data: <fault>): 
No cell mapping defined for objects of type 'NSManagedObject''
```

I was able to make it work by using :

```c
[self.tableController mapObjectsWithClass:[NSManagedObject class]
                      toTableCellsWithMapping:cellMapping];
```

Instead of :

```c
[self.tableController mapObjectsWithClass:[CrudCategory class]
                      toTableCellsWithMapping:cellMapping];
```

What I really don't get is that the exception states that there's no mapping for objects of type `NSManagedObject`, and when I use the `NSManagedObject` class instead of `CrudCategory` - which just inherits from `NSManagedObject` - everything's fine...

Here's my environment :

- ios5
- RestKit (last stable in github)
- ARC
- Storyboard

If someone has an idea : )

Thanks !

**EDIT - Solved:**
I solved this issue in the datamodel by specifying the proper class for each entity.

Answer (score 0):

Your CrudCategory class must have properties associated in it with the coredata model you have. Also you must be using this class to define mapping for the restkit mapping provider.

When you just use NSManagedObject class youre using a superclass which does not define the attributes in the subclass CrudCategory hence you see the issue. (I think!)

The question is, why do you want to use NSManagedObject Class instead of CrudCategory? Using CrudCategory is the right way of doing this as I use a similar method in my app + it is the method that Restkit exampls RKGithub uses.

Comment: I don't want to use NSManagedObject instead of CrudCategory. I had to do so...because of the exception thrown. 
My class is : interface CrudCategory : NSManagedObject

Comment: Anyway I would look into your app delegate incase there might be some error in how you setup your RKManagedObjectStore and checking that you import <CoreData/Coredata.h> in your CrudCategory.h.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I found the issue. It was actually in the data model, the entity class was not set properly!